# Erro - Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

tenho uma classe fragment...no qual estou inflando um arquivo xml. Esse fragment esta sendo chamado na MainActivity...porem quando executo aparece este erro

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.br.comunicacao/com.br.comunicacao.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML
>   file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30:
>   Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2215)
>                                                                           at com.br.comunicacao.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Esse é meu código da classe fragment:

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup conteiner, Bundle saveInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag_1, conteiner);

        return null;
    }


}
```

E esse é o da MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] lista = new String[]{"ALMOÇO","BEBIDAS","COMO ESTOU ME SENTINDO","FAMILIA"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 1){
                Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está retornando nulo na criação da view.

Tente:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup conteiner, Bundle saveInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag_1, conteiner, false);
}
```

Comment: Eu já tentei isso, porém ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tentou com o false, como terceiro parametro do método inflate?

Comment: Acabei de ver aqui o retorno nulo, quando retornei a view funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

**1º opção:**

Verifique o **layout_frag_1.xml**, se a tag pai tem o id do fragment, exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

**2ª opção:**

Verifique os imports, devem ser com supports, tendo em vista que vc está usando o **getSupportFragmentManager()**, exemplos:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

**3ª opção:**

No menu superior do seu AndroidStudio, clique em **Build** e depois em **Clean Project**